# how to add data into existing row Sql Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my Project I have student database and two webform. In database there are 6 columns( Email, Password, Name, Phone, ExamStatus, Score. I am inserting Email and Password value through webform1 and Name and password through another webform. Actually webform1 redirects to webform2.

here is my code behind file of webform1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class signin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void signupbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Punam\\Desktop\\Project\\App_Data\\OnlineLearning.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Student (Email, Password) values(@email, @password)", con );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtboxemail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtboxpass.Text);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Session["signup"] = txtboxemail.Text.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("profile.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

and codebehind file of webform2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public partial class profile : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["signup"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("signup.aspx");
            }
        }

        protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Punam\\Desktop\\Project\\App_Data\\OnlineLearning.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                string mail = Session["signup"].ToString();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Student set Name = @name, Phone = @phoneno where Email = + mail ", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtboxname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneno", txtboxphone.Text);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");

            }
        }
    }
```

But it is throwing error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'mail'.

Comment: `where Email = + mail` <= what is `mail`? You probably meant to pass another parameter here... (`where Email = @mail`) Treat it the same way you did with `@name` and `@phoneno`. *Most* of the time error messages tell you exactly why something is failing, you just have to read them...

Comment: Make `@mail` a parameter in your query.

Comment: Probably you meant to write @mail instead of + mail and add @ email parameter. And BTW you are designing a weak system (unencrypted password?)

Comment: On a side note you should [not use AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: mail is the string which I got from Session @lgor

Comment: Yahh, I am a new bie...just exploring right now.

Comment: If u can provide code it will be very helpful for me

Comment: I did, see my 1st comment. You can figure the rest out, it is not hard. All you have to do is read the comments and apply that to the existing code.

Comment: What should I use instead of AddWithValue @lgor

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@mail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mail;  (it is not really an issue here to use AddWithValue or not. You have more serious problems in your design)

Comment: what is that problem?

Comment: You are storing plain text password.

Comment: Right. I should implement with encryption to store password

Comment: `What should I use instead of AddWithValue` - in my comment I provided a link to an article which includes why it is bad practice and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Please replace following line to pass Email address in SQL Query which is in Session to db

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Student set Name = @name, Phone = @phoneno where Email = + mail ", con);
```

With

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Student set Name = @name, Phone = @phoneno where Email = @Email ", con);
```

2) Add @Email as Command parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", mail);
```